# How to solve three differential equations simultaneously in r

Tags: r

I am unsure about what to do for the input arguments in the function equation. Do I need to make the second input a vector? OR do I need an IF statement? Below is my current code.

```
ti <- 0
X0 <- .0005
S0 <- .04
P0 <- 0
umax <- .5
Pmax <- .109
ks <- .001
m <- 1
ms <- .008
Yh <- 2
Y <- 1
tf <- 15
Z <- c(S, P)

Keq <- function(X, S, P) {
  dX <- umax*X*(S/ks+S)*(1-(P/Pmax))^m
  dS <- -(dX/Y) - (ms*X)
  dP <- -(dX/Y) - (dX/Yh)+ms*X
  return(c(dX, dS, dP))
}

Y0 <- c(X0, S0, P0)

Rx <- ode45(Keq, ti, tf, Y0)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, you provided code has errors. The variables `S` and `P` are missing. What are they?

Comment: They are not given and I was told they were just dependent variables. I was only given the initial values X0, S0, and P0.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you got to write that code; For example, `ode45` does not exist in R or any package that I am aware of. Are you literally translating Matlab code?

Your question is unclear. This code runs without errors and outputs *something*, so maybe it helps you. Good luck.

Also [the manual of the `ode` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/deSolve/versions/1.20/topics/ode)  might help you, especially with regards to what your function `Keq` should expect as input and return as output.

P.S. Had you followed the [Best Practice guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the guide on how to write a [Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you would have probably received a helpful answer within a few hours.

---

Code:

```
library(deSolve) # if you get an error, run install.packages('deSolve') once
ti <- 0
X0 <- .0005
S0 <- .04
P0 <- 0
umax <- .5
Pmax <- .109
ks <- .001
m <- 1
ms <- .008
Yh <- 2
Y <- 1
tf <- 15
#Z <- c(S, P)

Keq <- function(time, state, params) {
  X <- state[1]
  S <- state[2]
  P <- state[3]
  dX <- umax*X*(S/ks+S)*(1-(P/Pmax))^m
  dS <- -(dX/Y) - (ms*X)
  dP <- -(dX/Y) - (dX/Yh)+ms*X
  return(list(c(dX, dS, dP)))
}

Y0 <- c(X0, S0, P0)

x <- seq(1,100,0.1)
Rx <- ode(Y0, x, Keq)
```